# How to find the root of a Tree Without knowing the objects

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to find the root of the tree wind a single node of id which is taken as an input

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = [] #lsit of childrens
    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
    def printing(self):
        print(self.data,'  -  node')
        for x in self.children:
            print(x.data,'  - child'
def add(node,li):
    for x in li:
        q = Node(x)
        node.add_child(q)
n = Node(0)
child = [2,3,4,1]
add(n,child)
p = Node(5)
n.add_child(p)
child2 = [6,7,8,9]
add(p,child2)
n.printing()
p.printing()

Output --
0   -  node
2   - child
3   - child
4   - child
1   - child
5   - child
5   -  node
6   - child
7   - child
8   - child
9   - child
```

This is how i create a tree, But when i need to check the root of 6 I only know about Class function not about p and n which i used in creating the tree.So how to find the root without the help of n and p.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to implement a `self.parent` attribute to each Node? Otherwise, you can only go downwards on the tree, and not reference back to the root, or parent of any given node. You would also need a fail safe, since this would start create a circular reference between the child nodes and the parent node.